# Is this the best way to unescape unicode escape sequences in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode

I have some text that contains Unicode escape sequences like \u003C.  This is what I came up with to unescape it:

`string.gsub(/\u(....)/) {|m| [$1].pack("H*").unpack("n*").pack("U*")}`

Is it correct?  (i.e. it seems to work with my tests, but can someone more knowledgeable find a problem with it?)

Comment: Right you are.  It's coming from Rails' ActiveSupport::JSON and getting decoded by ActiveSupport::JSON, but it's not decoding the \u escapes properly. (on Rails 2.1.2)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your regex, `/\u(....)/`, has some problems.

First of all, `\u` doesn't work the way you think it does, in 1.9 you'll get an error and in 1.8 it will just match a single `u` rather than the `\u` pair that you're looking for; you should use `/\\u/` to find the literal `\u` that you want.

Secondly, your `(....)` group is much too permissive, that will allow any four characters through and that's not what you want. In 1.9, you want `(\h{4})` (four hexadecimal digits) but in 1.8 you'd need `([\da-fA-F]{4})` as `\h` is a new thing.

So if you want your regex to work in both 1.8 and 1.9, you should use `/\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/`. This gives you the following in 1.8 and 1.9:

```
>> s = 'Where is \u03bc pancakes \u03BD house? And u1123!'
=> "Where is \\u03bc pancakes \\u03BD house? And u1123!"
>> s.gsub(/\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/) {|m| [$1].pack("H*").unpack("n*").pack("U*")}
=> "Where is μ pancakes ν house? And u1123!"
```

Using [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) to mangle the hex number into a Unicode character is probably good enough but there may be better ways.

Comment: Can also be useful to add this as an extension to the String class (I used String#utf8_decode).