# Ruby: UTF-8 incorrect input

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, utf-8

I have a .rb file that when run takes a string input for UTF-8, but for some reason the input is modified automatically. Here is an example of what my code looks like:

```
# encoding :UTF-8
.
.
.
print "Enter a UTF-8 input: "
text = gets.chomp
p text
```

So, if I input "\n\u001C\u0018\t\u001C", it prints out "\\n\\u001C\\u0018\\t\\u001C" which is not what I inputted!
Curious as I was, I compared the lengths, and it is the same 22. But, I know it is modified because when I run the text through a function in the same file, it reads it as the second one. I know this because when I ran my actual code through irb, it works as intended, but when I run it from the file, it doesn't do what I want.

**EDIT**: Sean answered the question I had about the printing, but it doesn't explain why when I use the value in text for a function within the same ruby file, it does not see it as it should. In other words, the function works perfectly on irb when I physically input the UTF string. So, if I input "\t\u001C\u001C".xor "key" to the function below, the result should be "bye". **Once again, this works in irb, but it doesn't work when I run it from a file!** When I run it from the file, it gives me a "'*': negative argument (ArgumentError)" when I don't get any errors running it from irb! Below is the function:

```
class String
  def xor(key)
    text = dup
    b1 = text.unpack("U*")
    b2 = key.unpack("U*")
    longest = key.length #[b1.length,b2.length].max
    b1 = [0]*(longest-b1.length) + b1
    b2 = [0]*(longest-b2.length) + b2
    result = b1.zip(b2).map{ |a,b| a^b }
    result.pack("U*")
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code results in a "unknown encoding name: TF-8 (ArgumentError)
" here (1..9.3). Try: `#encoding: UTF-8`.

Comment: I have edited the original post. Please take a look at EDIT, so you know exactly what problem I'm having. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question, it seems to have what you need for the second part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015778/is-this-the-best-way-to-unescape-unicode-escape-sequences-in-ruby this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230663/ruby-unescape-unicode-string

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because you are using:

```
p text
```

vs

```
puts text
```

When you use p, ruby outputs the result of:

```
puts text.inspect
```

Which will show you the extra \'s in there that are being used as escape characters. If you just used puts you will see the expected result!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped answer my first question, but it didn't answer my other question unfortunately. Please see my EDIT for my question! Once again, thanks!