# Convert unicode chars in ruby string which already encoded in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a string values which is encoded in UTF-8. But also they may contain unicode chars.

For ex;

```
"\u0131".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

"\u0131" is "ı".

how can i convert all unicode chars to utf-8?

Thanks

Çağdaş

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf-8 is an encoding for unicode characters. You don't have to convert anything, your characters are already encoded in utf-8. If they are displayed as `\u0131` or `ı` depends on the displaying program.

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm using rails and in my views strings ,which contains  "ı" for ex., are displayed with "\u0131". I thought it is a encoding problem but maybe is a view render problem. How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't know much about rails, but maybe some method is escaping your characters. You could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015778/is-this-the-best-way-to-unescape-unicode-escape-sequences-in-ruby right before displaying the string.

Comment: @Çağdaş, Apart from trying to unescape your string you could also try to find why it becomes escaped and prevent it. Where this string comes  from to you view, and how is it being outputted in it? Also note the difference in Ruby string literals: `"\u0131"` and `'\u0131'` are not the same and you should use *double* quotes so that \u is treated right.

Comment: @NIA data is coming from a graph database which store rdf in N3 notation. And they only support ASCII encoding for this notation. So i cant change it:)

Comment: @Çağdaş, any solution to this? I've having the same problem. My Rails view is just rendering the codes.

Answer (score 7):

Internally, in this string all unicode chars are already represented as utf-8 bytes. Let's check it.

```
> "\u0131".bytes.to_a
=> [196, 177]
```

OK, there are two bytes, but are they UTF-8 or UTF-16 bytes? The easiest way to check is to look at binary representation. Let's iterate each byte and print them in binary radix:

```
>> "\u0131".each_byte {|b| print b.to_s(2)};puts
1100010010110001
=> nil
```

This is the binary representation of your string — as you can see, that is correct UTF-8 two-byte sequence for char `100110001`, that is, `0x0131`:

```
110 00100 10 110001
---       --        ← UTF-8 markers for 2-byte char
    =====    ====== ← bits of your char
```

So the answer is — **do nothing**. The string is already utf-8, Q.E.D.