# Unicodes in file get escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Person` when i save a new Person through the console with unicode for eg:

```
p = Person.new
p.name = "Hans"
p.street = "Jo\u00DFstreet"
p.save
```

It returns on `p.street` `Joßstreet` what is correct. But when i try in my seeds to build from a file:

**file.txt**

```
Hans;Jo\u00DFstreet
Jospeh;Baiuvarenstreet
```

and run this in my seed:

```
File.readlines('file.txt').each do |line|
  f = line.split(';')
  p = Person.new
  p.name = p[0]
  p.street = p[1]
  p.save
end
```

Now when i call for eg: `p = Person.last` i get `p.street => "Jo\\u00DFstreet"`

I dont understand why the `\u00DF` gets escaped! What can i do to fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because escape sequences such as \u00DF are handled only in source code string literals, as a part of Ruby syntax.

When you read some file (or receive data from somewhere else) Ruby don't try to handle escape sequences and you should do it by your own code.

To unescape string you may use approaches described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015778/is-this-the-best-way-to-unescape-unicode-escape-sequences-in-ruby) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639642/whats-the-best-way-to-escape-and-unescape-strings), but maybe you'd be better to store initially unescaped text in your file.

Comment: Man you are the best! I tried to solve my problem for days! Thanks!